# Haskell... parse error on module

Tags: haskell, module, program-entry-point

what can be wrong with this? I've tried multiple solutions but it all ends up with the error on 'module' and in the = sign after the main. what the heck?!?!?!

```
printTabuleiro :: [[Char]] -> IO()
printTabuleiro [] = []
printTabuleiro (l :lt) = putStr l : printTabuleiro lt

module Main where

main = let 
          a = ["#####\n","###o##\n"] 
       in do printTabuleiro a
```

now I get this compiling errors, I do not understand the type matching issues here. Btw, I'm fairly new and not used to functional don't cannonize me to mars please.

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( visualisacao.hs, interpreted )

visualisacao.hs:14:27:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘[IO ()]’
    In the expression: putStr l : printTabuleiro lt
    In an equation for ‘printTabuleiro’:
        printTabuleiro (l : lt) = putStr l : printTabuleiro lt

visualisacao.hs:14:38:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[IO ()]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘printTabuleiro lt’
    In the expression: putStr l : printTabuleiro lt
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: Ps: Data.Char, System.IO and Data.List are imported.

Comment: `mapM_ putStrLn ["#####","###o##"]`

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, if your problem has been solved :). It doesn't have to go to me either.

Comment: I never forget :) so far it is what I've been trying to do.

Comment: The internet, I didn't fully understood your answer. Can you be more explicit and explain it please?

Comment: Please don't edit your question or title to indicate your problem is solved. That's what accepting an answer signals.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to declare your module first. Then you need to declare your imports. Then you can define your functions.

Answer (score 8):

The `module` declaration can only be preceded by comments and compiler pragmas like language extensions.  Put the `module Main where` line at the top of your file and everything else below it.  Imports must also come between the module declaration and any function or type declarations, so it should look like

```
module Main where

import Data.Char
import ...

printTabuleiro :: ...
printTabuleiro [] = ...

main = let
         a = ...
    in do printTabuleiro a
```

Comment: you should also mention that `printTabuleiro [] = []` produces a type error given the return type of `IO ()`

Comment: yes, I noticed that a little bit after posting. More of a mechanisation error. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, my problem was improper indenting (seriously!)
Make sure you're using three spaces instead of a TAB, and make sure things are properly subindented